# how to show/hide added subview on next navigation page in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, admob

I am adding google admob banner as subview to appdelegate.now on certain page i don't want that banner,

I am able to remove that using method defined in appdelegate but when I come back to previous page that banner remains hide.

Comment: Are u using the same reference of `admobController `?

Comment: No i have just declared an object of AdmobViewController class. how can i use the same reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have the reference of the AppDelegate class in the voiceviewcontroller.m, declare and define a method in AppDelegate to remove the admob view and then, call that method from voiceviewcontroller.

Comment: removing it is working fine.I have edited the question.please check out

Comment: Similarly declare and define a new method in AppDelegate to add the admob view. In viewWillDisappear of the voiceviewcontroller, call that method to add that as subview.

Answer (score 0):

```
admobviewcontroller.view.hidden = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[admobviewcontroller removeFromSuperview];
```